# Invalid syntax in gdalwarp

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp

I am trying to reproject and resize an image in QGIS python console. But i am getting invalid syntax error.

```
import gdal
fn = "D:\\satellite\\1.tif"
out = "D:\\1.tif"
gdal Warp(out,fn,srcSRS ="EPSG : 4326",dstSRS = "EPSG : 32614",width = 3400,height = 3400))
```

What seems to be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have a few syntax errors. Firstly, you need to use dot notation to call the `Warp` function e.g. `gdal.Warp()`.

Secondly, you have a space before the colons in your epsg code strings.

Lastly you have an extra closing parenthesis.

Try:

```
import gdal
fn = "D:\\satellite\\1.tif"
out = "D:\\1.tif"
gdal.Warp(out, fn, srcSRS = "EPSG: 4326", dstSRS = "EPSG: 32614", width = 3400, height = 3400)
```